# R-Markdown: print a string in a nice block quote

Tags: r, r-markdown

Let's say I have a really long string in variable, in R-Markdown

````
```{r}
string <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
```
````

How would you output the string in a nice block quote? (Just printing `string` is not "nice").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
>`r string`
```

Simple.

Answer (score 2):

Or:

````
---
title: String Block
output: html_document
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
string <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."

cat(paste0('> ', string))
```
````